# How to define a column to be the sum of two columns? i.e. a computed or expression field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I would like to include in my grid an extra column to reflect the up to date sum of two other columns:

```
const columnDef = [
    {headerName: 'x', field: 'x', type: 'numericColumn'},
    {headerName: 'y', field: 'y', type: 'numericColumn'},
    {headerName: 'z', function: (data) => data.x+data.y}
];
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a simple [valueGetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-getters/) to add the 2 values of your x and y fields.

Change your `columnDefs` to:

```
  const [columnDefs] = useState([
      {headerName: 'x', field: 'x', type: 'numericColumn'},
      {headerName: 'y', field: 'y', type: 'numericColumn'},
      {headerName: 'z', valueGetter: function(event) {
        return event.data.x + event.data.y;
      }}
  ]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-react-hello-world-forked-q4z244?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A15%2C1-21%2C6).

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you cannot set the value directly in the useState of your values. But you can edit the values in the useEffect after loading and insert the values you need. I set the total value to 0 by default. In the useEffect I update the values of the total field. Here is a modified example from the ag-gird documentation (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

export default function App() {
  const calcTotal = (count, price) => {
    return count * price;
  };

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', count: 3, price: 35000, total: 0 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', count: 3, price: 32000, total: 0 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', count: 3, price: 72000, total: 0 },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRowData((prevRowData) =>
      prevRowData.map((row) => ({
        ...row,
        total: calcTotal(row.count, row.price),
      }))
    );
  }, []);

  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price' },
    { field: 'count' },
    { field: 'total' },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact rowData={rowData} columnDefs={columnDefs}></AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let me know if that helps.